# Looping through JSON using Node.js

Tags: sql, json, node.js

I am trying to loop through JSON using Node so that I can call a stored procedure in a sql database. the JSON is:

```
[ { boardid: '1', accesid: '2' },
  { boardid: '2', accesid: '3' },
  { boardid: '8', accesid: '4' } ]
```

the pseudo code i want to implement is: (I have the UserID)

```
var data = req.body.addJSON

for each JSON object {
    con.query(
        "CALL addUserToBoard('" + UserID + "', '" + BoardID + "','" + AccessTypeID + "');",
        function(err, result, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: What is it you are asking? Please tell us what issues you are running into and what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this using a simple forEach,

```
var data = req.body.addJSON


data.forEach(value => {
    con.query("CALL addUserToBoard('" + UserID + "', '" + value.boardid + "','" + value.accesid + "');", function (err, result, fields) 
    {
        if (err) throw err;
    }); 
})
```

Comment: No problem. Please accept the answer as correct if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can always interate in an Object a follows

```
var jsonresponse = JSON.parse(data);
Object.keys(jsonresponse).forEach( function(param , index) {
    console.log(jsonresponse[param]);
    console.log(index);
});
```